# good solver for implementing Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

Please let me know what solver (such as GAMS, Gurobi, Lingo, Python, etc.) can be used to implement Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition on a linear programming model. I understand I can develop the whole algorithm by coding in some of these solvers. But, I'm looking for a ready-to-use tool or code. The model I'm dealing with has several coupling constraints. I need to decompose my model into a master and a subproblem (or a finite number of subproblems if the solver allows).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, [SAS](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_036/casmopt/casmopt_decomp_toc.htm) has the only commercial solver with an automated implementation of Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition.  You can use automatic block-detection routines or specify the block structure yourself.  From there, everything is automated, including parallelization of the subproblem solves.

Comment: [Dippy](https://pypi.org/project/coinor.dippy/) from coinor (free and open source) also does this. See for example this [paper](https://orsnz.org.nz/conf45/program/Papers/ORSNZ2010_OSullivan.pdf), or this [presentation](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/~ted/files/talks/DecompINFORMS12.pdf) by Ted Ralphs. That said, I am not sure it is still maintained, and its performances are probably much less effective than SAS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GCG](https://gcg.or.rwth-aachen.de/). It is open-source and has also a Python inteface called [PyGCGOpt](https://scipopt.github.io/PyGCGOpt/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).